# 728x90 Ad Size not showing ads on https

Tags: https, ads, google-dfp

We're in the middle of switching our website from http to https.

Our ads seem to be working on the https version of the website, we use DFP and we bring in competition via PreBid.

But for whatever reason, our 728x90 ads are always showing as house ads, whereas the 300x250, 320x250, and 300x600 ads are correctly working and showing ads.

Any idea why on the secure version of our website, the 728x90 ads wouldn't be working?

Comment: Are you seeing bids from the partners at all? It might be possible that the partners haven’t whitelisted the https address if you are not seeing bids—or tour prebid has hardcoded references to their http endpoint instead of https Do you have a URL that you can share where this is happening? (A lot of possible causes)

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic response for that situation. There are too many possible issues.

The first thing you need to do is to:

- Create a simple HTML file with the 728x90 slot inside it and of course the JavaScript code to call DFP.
- Open this HTML file with Chrome.
- Use the `F12` key to open [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/).
- Check the Console.

> For any unsecured resources, Chrome displays a “Mixed Content” message
>   in the Console. Some text will be in red or yellow.
>
> Red: Errors that indicate the resource was blocked.
>
> Yellow: Warnings that should be fixed.